# tstrsplit to different columns in one round

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table like the following:

```
myDT <- fread(
  "id,other,strformat,content
 1, other1, A:B,    a1:b1
 2, other2, A:C,    a2:c2
 3, other3, B:A:C,  b3:a3:c3
 4, other4, A:B,    a4:b4
 5, other5, XX:whatever,    xx5:whatever5
")
```

And I want to split the `content` column based on `strformat`, to get this:

```
   id  other   strformat       content    A    B    C   XX  whatever
1:  1 other1         A:B         a1:b1   a1   b1 <NA> <NA>      <NA>
2:  2 other2         A:C         a2:c2   a2 <NA>   c2 <NA>      <NA>
3:  3 other3       B:A:C      b3:a3:c3   a3   b3   c3 <NA>      <NA>
4:  4 other4         A:B         a4:b4   a4   b4 <NA> <NA>      <NA>
5:  5 other5 XX:whatever xx5:whatever5 <NA> <NA> <NA>  xx5 whatever5
```

I failed with `tstrsplit()` on `by=`:

```
myDT[, unlist(strsplit(strformat,':')):=tstrsplit(content,':'), by=strformat]
# Error in strsplit(strformat, ":") : object 'strformat' not found
```

So for now I resorted to using a cycle:

```
for (this.format in unique(myDT$strformat)){
  myDT[strformat==this.format, unlist(strsplit(this.format,':')):=tstrsplit(content,':')]
}
```

It does the job, but I'm still wondering what would be the right way with `by=`

Comment: A perfect scenario for [this PR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543). This should be just ```myDT[, `:=`(tstrsplit(content, ":", fixed = TRUE))]``` in a perfect world. Though I don't really understand you `strformat` column- is it supposed to be the pattern? Because, as it is, it's not really a valid pattern.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, well, if I understand correctly, that FR only addresses the issue of variable length, but not variable names. In my case, for example, the same `content` "foo:bar" should go to different columns depending on `format` column "A:B" vs "B:C"

Comment: Oh, so `strformat` are the column names? I thought it was supposed to be some splitting pattern, OK then.

Comment: yeah unfortunately it's complicated in my case (and it seems all the fancy solutions are slower than just the cycle - see the benchmarking I've added). But the case described in FR is absolutely realistic as well, I had it several times. Hope it will be implemented at some point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have tested 3 solutions kindly suggested by @akrun, with slight modifications. Skipped the last one because it has the column names hardcoded.

```
# define functions to compare:

require(splitstackshape)
f_csplit <- function(inpDT, col_format='strformat', col_content='content', sep=':'){
  invisible(inpDT[dcast(
    cSplit(inpDT, c(col_format, col_content), sep, "long"), 
    as.formula(paste('id',col_format,sep='~')), 
    value.var=col_content
  ), , on = .(id)])
}

f_lapply_str <- function(inpDT, col_format='strformat', col_content='content', sep=':'){
  invisible(inpDT[dcast(
    inpDT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, sep), recursive = FALSE), by = id, .SDcols = 2:3], 
    as.formula(paste('id',col_format,sep='~')),
    value.var=col_content
  ), on = .(id)])
}

require(tidyverse)
f_unnest <- function(inpDT, col_format='strformat', col_content='content', sep=':'){
  invisible(inpDT[dcast(
    unnest(inpDT[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, sep),by = id, .SDcols = 2:3]), 
    as.formula(paste('id',col_format,sep='~')), 
    value.var=col_content
  ), on = .(id)])
}

f_cycle <- function(inpDT, col_format='strformat', col_content='content', sep=':'){
  inpDT <- copy(inpDT); # in fact I don't even need to make a copy:
                        # := modifies the original table which is fine for me - 
                        # but for benchmarking let's make a copy  
  for (this.format in unique(inpDT[[col_format]])){
    inpDT[get(col_format)==this.format, unlist(strsplit(this.format,sep)):=tstrsplit(get(col_content),sep)]
  }
  invisible(inpDT)
}
```

It seems that solutions #2 (`lapply` of `strsplit`, without `cSplit`) and #3 (`unnest)` don't work correctly when I have any other columns in the table, it only works if I remove "other":

```
myDT[dcast(myDT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, ":"), recursive = FALSE), by = id, .SDcols = 2:3], id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
#      id  other   strformat       content    A    B    C   XX whatever
#   1:  1 other1         A:B         a1:b1    A    B <NA> <NA>     <NA>
#   2:  2 other2         A:C         a2:c2    A <NA>    C <NA>     <NA>
#   3:  3 other3       B:A:C      b3:a3:c3    A    B    C <NA>     <NA>
#   4:  4 other4         A:B         a4:b4    A    B <NA> <NA>     <NA>
#   5:  5 other5 XX:whatever xx5:whatever5 <NA> <NA> <NA>   XX whatever

myDT[dcast(unnest(myDT[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ":"),by = id, .SDcols = 2:3]), id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
# (same result as above)

myDT$other <- NULL
myDT[dcast(myDT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, ":"), recursive = FALSE), by = id, .SDcols = 2:3], id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
#      id   strformat       content    A    B    C   XX  whatever
#   1:  1         A:B         a1:b1   a1   b1 <NA> <NA>      <NA>
#   2:  2         A:C         a2:c2   a2 <NA>   c2 <NA>      <NA>
#   3:  3       B:A:C      b3:a3:c3   a3   b3   c3 <NA>      <NA>
#   4:  4         A:B         a4:b4   a4   b4 <NA> <NA>      <NA>
#   5:  5 XX:whatever xx5:whatever5 <NA> <NA> <NA>  xx5 whatever5

myDT[dcast(unnest(myDT[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ":"),by = id, .SDcols = 2:3]), id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
# (same correct result as above)
```

Here is the benchmarking with "other" columns removed:

```
# make a bigger table based on a small one:
myDTbig <- myDT[sample(nrow(myDT),1e5, replace = T),]
myDTbig[, id:=seq_len(nrow(myDTbig))]
myDTbig$other <- NULL

require(microbenchmark)
print(microbenchmark(
  f_csplit(myDTbig), 
  f_lapply_str(myDTbig), 
  f_unnest(myDTbig), 
  f_cycle(myDTbig), 
  times=10L
), signif=2)

# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min   lq mean median   uq  max neval
# f_csplit(myDTbig)      420  430  470    440  450  670    10
# f_lapply_str(myDTbig) 4200 4300 4700   4700 5100 5400    10
# f_unnest(myDTbig)     3900 4400 4500   4500 4800 5100    10
# f_cycle(myDTbig)        88   96   98     98  100  100    10
```

And with "other" columns kept:

```
# make a bigger table based on a small one:
myDTbig <- myDT[sample(nrow(myDT),1e5, replace = T),]
myDTbig[, id:=seq_len(nrow(myDTbig))]

require(microbenchmark)
print(microbenchmark(
  f_csplit(myDTbig), 
  f_cycle(myDTbig), 
  times=100L
), signif=2)

# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr min  lq mean median  uq  max neval
# f_csplit(myDTbig) 410 440  500    460 490 1300   100
# f_cycle(myDTbig)   84  93  110     96 100  270   100
```

And below is with my real dataset. Well, actually, only 1/10th of it: with the full one I had memory allocation error on `csplit` solution (while the one with the cycle worked fine).

```
myDTbig <- dt.vcf[1:2e6,]
myDTbig[,id:=seq_len(nrow(myDTbig))]

print(microbenchmark(
  f_csplit(myDTbig, 'FORMAT', 'S_1'), 
  f_cycle(myDTbig, 'FORMAT', 'S_1'), 
  times=5L
), signif=2)
# Unit: seconds
#                              expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval
# f_csplit(myDTbig, "FORMAT", "S_1") 15.0 16.0   16   16.0 16.0 17.0     5
# f_cycle(myDTbig, "FORMAT", "S_1")   4.9  4.9    6    5.7  5.8  8.5     5
```

Finally, I tested if having many levels in `format` column (i.e. how many cycles we have to run) will increase the time for the solution with the cycle:

```
myDTbig <- myDT[sample(nrow(myDT),1e6, replace = T),]
myDTbig[, strformat:=paste0(strformat,sample(letters,1e6, replace = T)),]
length(unique(myDTbig$strformat)) # 104
myDTbig[, id:=seq_len(nrow(myDTbig))]

print(microbenchmark(
  f_csplit(myDTbig), 
  f_cycle(myDTbig), 
  times=10L
), signif=2)
# Unit: seconds
#             expr  min  lq mean median  uq max neval
# f_csplit(myDTbig) 7.3 7.4  7.7    7.6 7.9 8.4    10
#  f_cycle(myDTbig) 2.7 2.9  3.0    2.9 3.0 3.8    10
```

So, as a conclusion - surprisingly, the cycle performed better than anything else for this task.

Comment: Thank you for the benchmarks.  It is very useful.  Is it possible to profile it to understand where it is taking more time

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit I still have to learn how to use profiling :/ I mean, I tried to run it from RStudio and not quite sure how to interpret the graph: 
https://imgur.com/a/tAE84su 
https://imgur.com/a/i3aQnn7

Comment: yeah, that is a difficult one.  May be split up the code and it may become easier `myDT1 <- cSplit(myDT, c("strformat", "content"), ":", "long"); myDT2 <- dcast(myDT1, id ~ strformat); myDT[myDT2, on = .(id)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `cSplit` and `dcast`.  With `cSplit`, split the 'strformat', 'content' strings into substring at the delimiter `:`, by specifying the 'direction' as "long", it expands the dataset, using `dcast`, change the 'long' format to 'wide' and join with the original data on 'id'

```
library(splitstackshape)
myDT[dcast(cSplit(myDT, c("strformat", "content"), ":", "long"),
             id ~ strformat), , on = .(id)]
#  id strformat  content    A    B    C
#1:  1       A:B    a1:b1   a1   b1 <NA>
#2:  2       A:C    a2:c2   a2 <NA>   c2
#3:  3     B:A:C b3:a3:c3   a3   b3   c3
#4:  4       A:B    a4:b4   a4   b4 <NA>
#5:  5       B:C    b5:c5 <NA>   b5   c5
```

---

Slightly modified version (without using `cSplit`) would be

```
myDT[dcast(myDT[, unlist(lapply(.SD, strsplit, ":"), 
    recursive = FALSE), by = id, .SDcols = 2:3], id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
```

---

Or with `tstrsplit` and `unnest`

```
myDT[dcast(unnest(myDT[, lapply(.SD, tstrsplit, ":"),
         by = id, .SDcols = 2:3]), id ~ strformat), on = .(id)]
```

---

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
myDT %>% 
  separate_rows(content) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(content = paste0(letters[1:3], readr::parse_number(content[1]))) %>%
  summarise(content = paste(replace(content, is.na(strformat), NA), 
                collapse=":")) %>% 
  right_join(myDT, by = "id") %>%
  separate(content.x, into = c("A", "B", "C")) %>%
  select(id, strformat, content = content.y, A, B, C)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#     id strformat content  A     B     C    
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 A:B       a1:b1    a1    b1    NA   
#2     2 A:C       a2:c2    a2    NA    c2   
#3     3 B:A:C     b3:a3:c3 a3    b3    c3   
#4     4 A:B       a4:b4    a4    b4    NA   
#5     5 B:C       b5:c5    NA    b5    c5
```

Comment: thank you @akrun! I am now running the benchmark on all those solutions - so far the cycle seems to be much faster :) . Unfortunately, solutions with `lapply` and `unnest` do not work if I have any other additional columns in the table (see updated example in the question - sorry for not having it from the beginning).

Comment: Also, I forgot to say that my columns (defined from `strformat`) are not always A,B,C - it can be any other names, not known in advance - so the `tidyverse` solution is also not very universal. Sorry again for the changes, I went too far with minimizing and simplifying my example.

Comment: @VasilyA  The first three solution depend on the `strformat` value.  Only the tidyverse solution have the `factor` issue

Comment: @VasilyA  Regarding your benchmark, is that on a bigger dataset with 1e6 rows or so.  If that is the case, I am a bit surprised that looping for those many rows is faster than just a single join/dcast

Comment: yes, my real table has 2e7 rows. At the same time, I only have 5 unique values in the "format" column, so the cycle is only called 5 times. But even with 20x more it's still faster (see the benchmarking - I added it as an answer to keep the question more compact).